# Validate API request attributes recursively

Tags: laravel, validation, recursion

I am developing dynamic query builder for the admin users and for the same I am implementing POST API request to store all conditions together in database.

I am stuck with the validation of POST json. I tried different ways to prepare rule array.
Below is the code snippet for validation part.

Controller Action

```
public function saveConditions(ConditionRequest $request, Action $action): JsonResponse
{
    dd($request, $action);
}
```

ConditionRequest.php

```
use App\Admin\Http\Requests\FormRequest;
use App\Rules\Conditions\RecursiveConditionRule;
class ConditionRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'conditions' => ['required', 'array'],
            'conditions.*' => [new RecursiveConditionRule()],
        ];
   }
```

}

RecursiveConditionRule.php

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Closure;
class RecursiveConditionRule implements ValidationRule
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        $this->validateRecursive($attribute, $value);
    }
    protected function validateRecursive($attribute, $value): void
    {
        $conditionRules = [
            $attribute => 'array',
            "$attribute.type_slug" => ['required', Rule::in(ConditionType::all())],
            "$attribute.subjected_table" => ['required_if:type_slug,simple', 'string'],
            "$attribute.table_alias" => ['required_if:type_slug,simple', 'string'],
            "$attribute.logical_operator" => ['required', Rule::in(Operator::all())],
            "$attribute.relation_and_column" => ['nullable', 'string'],
            "$attribute.column_type" => ['nullable', 'string', Rule::in(ColumnType::all())],
            "$attribute.filter_criteria" => ['nullable', 'string', Rule::in(FilterCriteria::all())],
            "$attribute.filter_value" => ['nullable', 'string'],
            "$attribute.sub_conditions" => ['required_if:type_slug,group', 'array'],
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make([$attribute => $value], $conditionRules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }
        if (isset($value['sub_conditions']) && is_array($value['sub_conditions'])) {
            foreach ($value['sub_conditions'] as $index => $subCondition) {
                $this->validateRecursive("$attribute.sub_conditions.$index", $subCondition);
            }
        }
    }
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute is invalid.';
    }
}
```

and below is my JSON request sample (It is with dummy data.)

```
{
    "conditions": [
        {
            "type_slug": "simple",
            "subjected_table": "users",
            "table_alias": "u",
            "logical_operator": "and",
            "relation_and_column": "name",
            "column_type": "string",
            "filter_criteria": "contains",
            "filter_value": "john"
        },
        {
            "type_slug": "group",
            "logical_operator": "or",
            "sub_conditions": [
                {
                    "type_slug": "simple",
                    "subjected_table": "orders",
                    "table_alias": "o",
                    "logical_operator": "and",
                    "relation_and_column": "invoice.total",
                    "column_type": "numeric",
                    "filter_criteria": "greater_than",
                    "filter_value": 100
                },
                {
                    "type_slug": "simple",
                    "subjected_table": "orders",
                    "table_alias": "o",
                    "logical_operator": "and",
                    "relation_and_column": "status",
                    "column_type": "string",
                    "filter_criteria": "contains",
                    "filter_value": "completed"
                },
                {
                    "type_slug": "group",
                    "logical_operator": "or",
                    "sub_conditions": [
                        {
                            "type_slug": "simple",
                            "subjected_table": "orders",
                            "table_alias": "o",
                            "logical_operator": "and",
                            "relation_and_column": "total",
                            "column_type": "numeric",
                            "filter_criteria": "greater_than",
                            "filter_value": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "type_slug": "simple",
                            "subjected_table": "orders",
                            "table_alias": "o",
                            "logical_operator": "and",
                            "relation_and_column": "status",
                            "column_type": "string",
                            "filter_criteria": "contains",
                            "filter_value": "completed"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type_slug": "simple",
            "subjected_table": "products",
            "table_alias": "p",
            "logical_operator": "or",
            "relation_and_column": "title",
            "column_type": "string",
            "filter_criteria": "contains",
            "filter_value": "apple"
        },
        {
            "type_slug": "group",
            "logical_operator": "and",
            "sub_conditions": [
                {
                    "type_slug": "simple",
                    "subjected_table": "orders",
                    "table_alias": "o",
                    "logical_operator": "and",
                    "relation_and_column": "total",
                    "column_type": "numeric",
                    "filter_criteria": "greater_than",
                    "filter_value": 200
                },
                {
                    "type_slug": "simple",
                    "subjected_table": "products",
                    "table_alias": "p",
                    "logical_operator": "or",
                    "relation_and_column": "title",
                    "column_type": "string",
                    "filter_criteria": "contains",
                    "filter_value": "banana"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It gives me below response::

```
{
    "message": "This field is required. (and 1 more error)",
    "errors": {
        "conditions.0.type_slug": [
            "This field is required."
        ],
        "conditions.0.logical_operator": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

It seems validator is not receiving attribute and values properly for the recursive call. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validator fails since, given your `$rules` array, it expects input data in the form of:

```php
$input = [
  "conditions" => [
    ["type_slug": "simple", ...], [...], [...],
  ]
];
```

but instead you are providing it with data in the form of:

```php
$input = [
  "conditions.0" => ["type_slug": "simple", ...],
  "conditions.1" => ["type_slug": "simple", ...],
];
```

A simple work around it to remove the "dot" syntax from your input keys.

```php
    protected function validateRecursive($attribute, $value): void
    {
        // replace "." with whatever making "conditions.0" into "conditions_0"
        // now Laravel does not assume you are using dot syntax
        $attribute = str_replace('.', '_', $attribute);
        $conditionRules = [
            $attribute => 'array',
            "$attribute.type_slug" => ['required', Rule::in(ConditionType::all())],
            "$attribute.subjected_table" => ['required_if:type_slug,simple', 'string'],
            "$attribute.table_alias" => ['required_if:type_slug,simple', 'string'],
            "$attribute.logical_operator" => ['required', Rule::in(Operator::all())],
            "$attribute.relation_and_column" => ['nullable', 'string'],
            "$attribute.column_type" => ['nullable', 'string', Rule::in(ColumnType::all())],
            "$attribute.filter_criteria" => ['nullable', 'string', Rule::in(FilterCriteria::all())],
            "$attribute.filter_value" => ['nullable', 'string'],
            "$attribute.sub_conditions" => ['required_if:type_slug,group', 'array'],
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make([$attribute => $value], $conditionRules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
        }
        if (isset($value['sub_conditions']) && is_array($value['sub_conditions'])) {
            foreach ($value['sub_conditions'] as $index => $subCondition) {
                $this->validateRecursive("$attribute.sub_conditions.$index", $subCondition);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your validation key should be: `"$attribute.*.type_slug"` rather than `"$attribute.type_slug"`

However personally, I would focus in building the correct rules array from the input rather than trying to validate recursively. So you can loop through the input recursively and input rules into `$rules` depending on the given fields.

Comment: value of $attribute contains current count itself for example `conditions.0` , `conditions.1` and so on.

Comment: well than the data you are passing into the `Validator::make([$attribute => $value])` is probably incorrect, since the data you are passing is `"conditions.0" => ["type_slug" => ...]` not `"conditions" => [ 0 => ["type_slug" => ...], ...]`

Comment: @Avnee.Angel was the `Validator::make([$attribute => $value])` part the issue?

Comment: yes, I have doubt If it's able to receive the input properly.

Comment: you can try building a new key that does NOT use dot syntax, something like `$attribute = str_replace('.', '_', $attribute);` before you create your rules and the validator instance. That should result in the correct syntax I think

Comment: It works like charm. Can you post this as answer, I can flag as best answer?
Thank you so much. @kris